# $('#MyForm').valid() always returning false

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2, jquery-post

I am trying to post my form using ajax post in mvc razor. And I am trying to validate the form before posting to database. But Even though form is valid, it is blocking the form to post.

```
$(function () {
    $('#MyForm').submit(function () {
        if ($('#MyForm').valid()) {
        //$("#divLoading").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Something", "Something")',
            data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (xhr) {
                $("#Message").text(xhr.statusText);
                $('#divLoading').hide('fast');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //$('#divLoading').hide('fast');
                if (result.IsSuccess) {
                    $("#Message").html(result.Message);
                    $('#MyForm')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Begin form contains

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Something", "Something", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @id = "MyForm" }))
{
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why do you have ProviderForm and MyForm?

Comment: Try calling `$(this).validate();` before the `if` statement

Comment: I think you should change your method. First try to check if form is valid and after this is it's valid submit it, I think is no reason to do what you want to do.anywhere  form will not be submitted if it's not valid

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you still use form default action, so page will reload before getting ajax response. Try this:

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

if ($('#MyForm').valid()) {
    //$("#divLoading").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Something", "Something")',
        data: $('#MyForm').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr) {
            $("#Message").text(xhr.statusText);
            $('#divLoading').hide('fast');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //$('#divLoading').hide('fast');
            if (result.IsSuccess) {
                $("#Message").html(result.Message);
                $('#MyForm')[0].reset();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

where this is the difference:

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```